# Assembly: How to define the Format Shifting (SHL,SHR)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, bit-shift

How i can know how much to be shifted with using `shl` or `shr` in assembly.
for example :

```
0x111111111111116f
```

To remove the `11111111111111`  I will use `shl` and `shr`.

```
 mov    rsi, 0x111111111111116f
 shl    rsi, 0x38
 shr    rsi, 0x38
```

So, what is the meaning of `0x38` specifically?
How do we know how many bits will be shifted?

Comment: The number of times you shift the bits, 56 times.  Very little point in doing it this way, use `and rsi,0xff` instead.

Comment: Thank you sir. Thats what  i look for..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what is the meaning 0x38 specifically? How do we can know how much will be shifted?

0x38 is a number in the hexadecimal notation. In decimal it represents 56.

```
shl    rsi, 0x38
```

The value in `RSI` (whatever it may represent) will be shifted to the left 56 bits.

```
shr    rsi, 0x38
```

The value in `RSI` (whatever it may represent) will be shifted to the right 56 bits.